# Best method for sending large pandas dataframe to SQL database?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a pandas dataframe which has 10 columns and 10 million rows.

I have created an empty table in pgadmin4 (an application to manage databases like MSSQL server) for this data to be stored.

However, when running the following command:

```
my_dataframe.to_sql('name_of_sql_table',connection, index = False, if_exists = 'append', method="multi")
```

It takes a very long time in order to run and often crashes my jupyter kernel given that the process is so long/runs out of memory.

Is there any advisable methods for speeding up the "sending pandas to sql table"?

Some things i can think of would be to split the data into say 1million row chunks then send them one at a time - appending the rows as you run the `to_sql()` method.

I do not have the option of directly loading the data into pgadmin4 - my only method is to send data from python to pgadmin.

Comment: I'd suggest you try the splitting method first, that should be very straightforward and if memory on the local machine is the issue it should help.

Comment: Even 1M rows is a lot for a sql server command to run in one time, especially for production system were you want stability. Best guess would be to split. 
I used to have a loop running and use `df.iloc[i:i+chuncksize].to_sql(....)`, with i incremented by chuncksize every time

Comment: I'd suggest a chunk size of perhaps 10k-100k if you make it too small you will add a lot of transaction overheads and things will start to get slower again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

If this applies to your version of `pandas`, use

```
df.to_sql("table_name", 
          connection, 
          index=False, 
          if_exists='append',
          chunksize=25000,
          method=None)
```

Your query might be crashing because you're using `method='multi'`, as this does the following:

> method : {None, ‘multi’, callable}, default None
>
> Controls the SQL insertion clause used:
>
> ‘multi’: Pass multiple values in a single INSERT clause.
>   callable with signature (pd_table, conn, keys, data_iter).
>   Details and a sample callable implementation can be found in the section insert method.

Which means that `pandas` would construct the statement in memory for *all rows*. Using `chunksize` and one `INSERT` statement per row will allow `pandas` to chunk-up the save to db.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue as well but i do not use method='multi' and when using the chunksize=1000 it was crashing with below error.

ProgrammingError("(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request. (8003) (SQLExecDirectW)')",),

so, i have divide my number of columns with 2100 and use 150 as the chunksize. If there is a better way then please do let me know.